# Add success message just like add error Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to show success message just like `$this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid Promo Code');` this code but unable to do this is there any way to achieve this functionality:
My model code :

```
  public function rules()
    {
         return [
            ['referralCode', 'validateReferralCode'],
    ];
    }
```

And this is function for validation :

```
public function validatePromoCode($attribute, $params){

    if ($this->$attribute != '') {
        $model = PromoCode::find()
                    ->where(['promo_code'=>$this->promoCode,'status'=>1])
                    ->andWhere('end_date<='.time())->one();
        if(!$this->hasErrors() && ($model))
        {  
            // want to add success message here 
            $this->addSuccess($attribute, 'You will get 20 points');
            return true;
        }else{
             $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid Promo Code');
        }
    }

    return $this->referralCode;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [Yii2 Model Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html) says - there's no method like `addSuccess()`. Only way to do this is to write your own functionality to handle this methods, and proper javascript to handle inputs.